# Export After Effects layers to multi layered Quicktime movie file

Tags: video, quicktime, video-editing, adobe-after-effects

Is it possible to export multiple After Effects layers to a multi layered Quicktime movie file natively or using an additional application?

AE: CS5
Qt: 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not, neither with Adobe Premiere.